# Bootstrap 3 for Razor Html Action List

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, action

I made a list with the following MVC5 C# code to create the menu

```
public ActionResult List()
        {
            List<Menu> entity = _menuService.List();
            List<MenuModel> model = new List<MenuModel>();

            foreach (var item in entity)
            {
                model.Add(new MenuModel() {
                    Id = item.Id,
                    Title = item.Title,
                    Priority = item.Priority
                });
            }

            return PartialView("_List",model);
        }
```

Next, I used the following Razor in the Index document

```
<h2>Menu List</h2>

<a class="badge , btn btn-success" href="/Dashboard/Menu/Create">
    Create Menu
</a>

<hr />

@Html.Action("List", "Menu", new { area = "Dashboard"})
```

Now how can I use bootstrap classes for this Razor

Comment: Do you mean you want to pass the model by `@Html.Action`?

Comment: No, I want to use bootstrap class for this Razor